# What is the differece between a pomeron and a glueball?

Tags: particle-physics, gluons

What is the differece between a [pomeron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomeron) and a [glueball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball)?   I thought that glueballs were states made only of gluons, and pomerons were states of an even number of gluons. But apparently there is a difference that I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

One has to remember that back in the 1960's the dominant theory to model the plethora of resonances found in elemenary particle studies was [Regge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regge_theory) theory

> In quantum physics, Regge theory  is the study of the analytic properties of scattering as a function of angular momentum, where the angular momentum is not restricted to be an integer multiple of ħ but is allowed to take any complex value.

[In this review's](https://cds.cern.ch/record/434158/files/0004078.pdf) figures are the experimental  trajectories with their fit to theory.

The Pomeron was a  Regge trajectory where there was just a type of elastic scattering.

At present the quark model and QCD calculations  dominate the theory , and  there is an effort to identify Regge trajectories with QCD concepts, for [example this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.02494),  does connect "glueball"  states with the Pomeron trajectory as poles on it. Glueballs as far as I can gather exist in other trajectories too.

So in current research the Pomeron is a trajectory on which glueballs can be modeled in order to reproduce the experimental successes of the 1960's Regge trajectories.

Just a note, that AFAIK string theories also are able to embed the successes of the Regge trajectories